# How can I change my buttons to disabled if a retrieve takes more than a second?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form on my application with a button for retrieve. When a user clicks the button then data is retrieved. This could be almost instant or take several seconds. What I would like is for the button to be disabled if the retrieve has been in progress for more than 1 second. Here's what I have so far:

In my application controller:

```
this.state = {};
```

In a child controller:

```
this.retrieve = function () {
            app.state.get = true;

            $http({
                url: '/api/TestData',
                method: "GET"
            }).success(function (result) {
                app.state.get = false;
            });
        };
```

In the HTML I have:

```
<button ng-disabled="app.state.get"
        ng-click="test.retrieve()">
   Retrieve
</button>
<button ng-disabled="app.state.get">
   Another button
</button>
<button ng-disabled="app.state.get">
   Another button
</button>
```

There's more to the application but this is the basics of what I have. Note that I actually have a few buttons and controls and I would like them all to be disabled.

I now I could use something like a request interceptor but the problem I am trying to address is how can I put some delay on the disabling of the buttons and other controls.

Any help and suggestions thanks in advance.

Comment: why after one second? in my opinion the most preferable way is to disable it immediately if you do not want multiple requests at once (for example if users double click on it)

Comment: That was really just an example. I have tried disabling it immediately and as there are multiple buttons then everything on the screen flashes. I think if needed I could put some additional logic in the retrieve to stop double clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative to disabling the button:

### Throttle the execution of web requests.

Underscore has great utils to do that. The method is called [`throttle()`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Example:

```
    var getData = function () {
        app.state.get = true;

        $http({
            url: '/api/TestData',
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function (result) {
            app.state.get = false;
        });
    };
    this.retrieve = _.throttle(getData, 1000);
```

Now, the method will only be executed at most once per second, no matter how often someone clicks on the button. The first request will be made immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try using: **[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout)**

Angular's wrapper for `window.setTimeout`. The `fn` function is wrapped into a try/catch block and delegates any exceptions to `$exceptionHandler` service.

```
$timeout(fn[, delay][, invokeApply]);
```

A Sample Example is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/6uKAT/22/)**

If you want to disable the button after 3 seconds try like

**Script**

```
$http({
        url: '/api/TestData',
           method: "GET"
      }).success(function (result) {
            $timeout(function(){app.state.get = false}, 3000);  
      });
```

But as what @Alp said, why do you need to delay the button disabling

Comment: That's not what he wants. He wants to disable the button only if the promise takes too long to respond. Set  `var timer = $timeout(function(){app.state.get = true}, 1000)` before the `$http` call and cancel it on the `success` method with `$timeout.cancel(timer)`. This way, if the call takes less than 1 sec, the button won't be disabled, and if it does it will.